# Magento Amazon Checkout Signature Problems

Tags: magento

I see there are some people that got Amazon’s payment module working w/ Magento 1.5 and 1.6

I’m on 1.6.1 and I ALMOST have it working. Everything works great in Sandbox mode, when I have “Sign_XML_Cart” option disabled from the Magento side and also have it disabled from the Amazon side in the Checkout Pipeline Settings.

However, when this option is enabled, as it needs to be in production mode, I get this error from Amazon:

The order could not be authenticated. Detail: Your signature [xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx=] does not match the signature that we expect.

Was anybody else able to solve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Bonez, unfortunately I don't have an answer for you, but I'm running Mage 1.6 and really can't get the Checkout by Amazon plugin working at all. I've also tried once before while running 1.5, and just kept getting error after error. I've seen a ton of forum posts from others with the same problem. If you have any tips on how to get this plugin even semi-working, please share!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I had an extra space on the end of one of my API keys, when I copied and pasted over from Amazon's site. That extra space will cause a signature mismatch.